# Indexing composite types with Lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing

Currently I'm building a search tool as a project where the I index objects created from multiple database tables (i.e. people and things they do). I was wondering if there as a better way of going about this other than creating objects corresponding to each of the combination of people/things (there are thousands of each).

E.g. Creating an object that corresponds to Person 1 - Thing 1, and another to Person 1 - Thing 2 for all the N things that Person 1 does. Then, indexing that collection of objects. Then doing the same thing for Person 2.

Comment: Please give an example. It is not very clear as to what you are trying to ask.

Comment: If I understood correctly I suggest you create a View in your db that would join those two tables so that each person has a single line in view with one column that would concatenate all thing the person does (which would become multivalue field in Lucene).

Answer (score 0):

you  might use Join functionality if you dont want to denormalize the records. Look at [this article](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/405872/maximized) for starters. Performance would be worse than denormalizing but it could be good enough.